# Why is prepare for segue not sending image swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Im trying to send an image to another view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "cropSegue") {

        let crop : CropViewController =  segue.destination as! CropViewController
        crop.cropImage = image
        print("prepared")
    }
}
```

and on the receiving end

```
class CropViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var cropImage : UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imageView.image = cropImage
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Im not sure what's going wrong, but the image isn't being displayed, even thought the prepare for segue is being called. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Move your CropViewController code to *viewWillAppear()*. I'll bet it will work. Also, you can set a breakpoint to see what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure that at this point `crop.cropImage = image` your `image` is not nil?

Comment: My guess is that your segue identifier isn't "cropSegue", but set a breakpoint and find out. What is happening in prepareForSegue

Comment: Your code should work perfectly. Please cross check **segue name**, make sure **image is not nil** during segue , and check wether all **outlets are connected** properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class CropViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var cropImage : UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let image = cropImage {
         self.imageView.image = image
    }        
}
```